# Distinct of Enumerable.Select of nested List in C#

Tags: c#, linq, select, distinct

```
public class Country
{
    public List<State> States { get; set; } = new List<State>();
}

public class State
{
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; } = new List<City>();
}

public class City
{
    public decimal IdSeaLevel { get; set; }
}
```

`IdSeaLevel` Has these possible expected values: `0, 1, 2`.

Then is needed to check al values inserted by user to prevent some different value.

Suppose that the user send us an country (object of `Country` class) with its list filled (and nested too).

**How to get all **`Distinct`** `IdSeaLevel` inserted value by the user?**

I was thinking like:

```
List<decimal> AllowedIdSeaLevellist = new List<decimal>(new decimal[] { 0, 1, 2 });
```

Now, I get a Distict inserted Values

```
HashSet<decimal> SentIdSeaLevelSet = country.States
                .Select(s => s.Cities.IdSeaLevel).ToHashSet();
```

Check

```
bool badRequest= SentIdSeaLevelSet
    .Where(s => AllowedIdSeaLevellist.All(a => a != s)).Any();
```

Comment: So, you want to know if any of the country's states' cities  have an idsealevel not in the list? And you just want a book of if any are/not? Or do you want the city that has them? Or the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.SelectMany` will map List of lists into single list (flattened)

```
var allSeaLevels = country.States
   .SelectMany(s => s.Cities)
   .Select(city => city.SeaLevelId)
   .ToHashSet();
```

To get "invalid" sea levels you can alternatively to gather them while looping through sealevels.

```
var validSeaLevels = new[] { 0, 1, 2 }.ToHashSet();

var invalidSeaLevels = country.States
   .SelectMany(s => s.Cities)
   .Select(city => city.SeaLevelId)
   .Where(level => validSeaLevels.Contains(level) == false)
   .ToArray();

if (invalidSeaLevels.Any())
{
    return BadRequest(invalidSeaLevels);
}
```

Comment: Note that it's a bit of a performance hit to get every invalid value just to then ask for the Any, which would have otherwise stopped much sooner, e.g. `country.States.SelectMany(s => s.Cities).Any(city => city.SeaLevelId is < 0 or > 2)`

Comment: Yes, the final `.ToArray()` is a bottleneck if you don't need to capture all the failures first.

Answer (score 1):

This type of deep linking is where `SelectMany<T>` becomes helpful:

```
HashSet<decimal> SentIdSeaLevelSet = country.States
                .SelectMany(s => s.Cities.Select(c => c.IdSeaLevel)).Distinct().ToHashSet()
```

We want to project the `IdSeaLevel` but `Cities` is a List, so at some point you need the inner `Cities.Select()` but that can be inside or after the `SelectMany` which effectively flattens the hierarchy so that all of the nested `Cities` become a single list, the following would also work:

```
HashSet<decimal> SentIdSeaLevelSet = country.States
               .SelectMany(s => s.Cities).Select(c => c.IdSeaLevel).Distinct().ToHashSet()
```

I prefer to use projection first inside the `SelectMany` it we never need any other properties from the `City` objects (the first example) but different applications and structures might dictate that the second expression performs better.

For the final comparison your logic looks ok, another way to compare lists is by using except:

```
bool badRequest= SentIdSeaLevelSet
    .Except(AllowedIdSeaLevellist).Any();
```

This is functionally equivalent to your previous comparison and works because the types of the collections being compared are the same, runtime might be marginally faster but at this level you base your decision on code readability,  which is a subjective topic on its own, but I prefer the except version specifically when we are comparing lists.

Comment: This is good but there's no reason to call Distinct before creating the HashSet